# The meaning of "All that’s French for a liver pill."

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> “Eyes, Pansay—all Eyes, Brain, and Stomach. And the greatest of these
> three is Stomach. You’ve too much conceited Brain, too little Stomach,
> and thoroughly unhealthy Eyes. Get your Stomach straight and the rest
> follows. **And all that’s French for a liver pill.** I’ll take sole
> medical charge of you from this hour! for you’re too interesting a
> phenomenon to be passed over.”

This is from ["The Phantom Rickshaw" by Rudyard Kipling](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2806/2806-h/2806-h.htm#link2H_4_0001).

I don't understand the meaning of

> And all that’s French for a liver pill.

Answer (score 20):

It's not a common expression in modern English.

"All that" means "all the words that I just spoke".  And "French" is used jokingly as "language that isn't understood".  So he means:

> All this talking about "conceited brain and too little stomach" is hard to understand. But to make it simple for you, it all means that you should take this liver pill.

A "liver pill" is actually a laxative, and were often sold as "cure-alls" by charlatans.  The whole monologue is "patter": fast talk to get someone to buy a product.

The first part of the patter is a modification of a line from the Bible "faith, hope, charity, these three; but the greatest of these is charity"

Almost any foreign language could be substituted in place of "French" but it would be natural for an English speaker to refer to a language spoken close to England: French or Dutch would be natural, or even "double dutch".  "Latin" or particularly "Greek" is also common, from when these were commonly taught to high achieving pupils at school.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the meaning at all when I first read it. I was thinking that it was a pun on foie gras (french goose liver) as take a pill in place of eating everything that is French but it didn"t make any sense. Thank you for explaining it so well!

Comment: References to Greek are much older than the teaching of Greek in elite English schools, which enjoyed a rise in status during the Enlightenment (18th Century) and peaked toward the end of the 19th Century. In Shakespeare's Julius Caesar (1599), Casca says of Cicero's  speeches "it was Greek to me".

Comment: The whole monologue is "patter": fast talk to get someone to buy a product. **This is a false statement if you read the story**. Heatherlegh, the Doctor, kept, in addition to his regular practice, a hospital on his private account Therefore if he was doing pro bono work he is hardly a Charlatan.  The doctor has also just diagnosed indigestion "when I’ve cured you, young man, let this be a lesson to you to steer clear of women and **indigestible food** till the day of your death.”

Comment: This answer would work if the text was “... and all that French for...” — but it’s not. It reads “and all that *is* French”. It clearly means “and everything that is French for a liver pill”. Not “and all the verbiage above for a lover pill”.

Comment: And "French" is used jokingly as "language that isn't understood" **Surely this must be a false statement** In 19th Century Britain Middle class boys went to Grammar schools and Grammar schools originally taught Latin. Later the range of subjects increased to modern standards. However French Latin and Greek were fairly commonly studied languages in the 19th Century.  By early to mid to late 19th Century Education for middle class girls had become common place and an increasing number of poor children attended church schools, by the 1870's all children were required by law to attend school.

Comment: @Brad - French is a 'language that isn't understood' by a big majority of British people today, let alone 120 years ago.

Comment: @Brad French being a commonly studied language does not mean that a majority of the population would understand it, even if school was mandatory. Even in modern times it’s very common for someone who learns a second language to not retain almost any of it unless they actively use it, and beyond school there would have been little use for any second languages except maybe Liturgical Latin for most people other than diplomats or merchants in late 19th century England.

Comment: @Jivan no, that wouldn't work at all. "_and all that French for..._" would mean (nonsensically) "all that French (language) was used for..." it doesn't make sense. It is only with the _is_ that it does make sense and can be parsed just as this answer explains. Consider the equivalent "Bonjour is French for good morning", you need the _is_ there.

Comment: @Jivan I think you're not seeing that "all that is French" can be parsed in two different ways, the one you already see ([all] that is French) and the one that was most probably meant ([all that] is French for...).

Comment: I would say that "all that" refers to just "get your stomach straight", because I can't see how the earlier sentences are anything but a preamble.

Comment: @Zachiel now you say this, I actually believe you’re right. Makes more sense like this.

Answer (score 3):

The French language is occasionally used as a symbol for "a language the listener isn't really sure-footed in". That gives the speaker the chance to hide something (because the listener doesn't really understand all the details), or to make something appear different (for example, more valuable) than it actually is.

See for example the phrase "pardon my French" or "excuse my French". This basically means "please excuse me for using language you're uncomfortable with" - be it because the listener doesn't speak the language that good, or (as it is mostly used today), because you're using swear words.

In this case, the "French" is supposedly used to hide the more simple nature of the medicine the doctor applies. So,

> And all that’s French for a liver pill.

basically means something like

> And all what I just said was just a fancy way to describe a liver pill.

Another example might be

> A "number ninja" is just French for an accountant.

Comment: As you correctly state the phrase "pardon my French" or "excuse my French" is used or was used when you say something uncouth or worse.

Comment: @Brad - what a way to describe la langue de Voltaire, which is arguably more elegant, precise, and expressive than English. Look at all the things English can't say and and has to borrow. Carte blanche, tout le monde au balcon, jeunesse dorée, épater les bourgeois, etc etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Languages are influencing each other all the time. I wouldn't take the fact that one language adopts loan words from another as a sign of inferiority. Just look at "le weekend", "le pull", "le parking", "lousse" (from "loose"), "contacter" (from "to contact") and so forth. I know many French are quite defensive of their language, but those quarrels about "keeping the language pure" always seem quite ridiculous to me.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck - Not just English. On peut faire le dolce far niente. Maybe it is because I have been a Francophile for approaching 60 years that I perceive English weaknesses that French remedies. Of course it goes the other way. When I go to France there is sometimes a struggle to speak French because younger people want to try out their English, but older people are OK. A nice French lady in a train once thought I was maybe Swiss, which flattered me greatly.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Just because I am reporting on the use does not say I agree with it. Please do not shoot the messenger :) P.S. Not to keen on the politic (burnt sheep and the fishy stuff) and the fact they declined to join the commonwealth but I have no problem with the language.

Answer (score -4):

It means **everything**

All that is French means everything from France. Which is used to imply that "everything else in the world" be fine if you take medicine for your liver.

Remember "The Phantom Rickshaw" was first printed in 1888 which coincided with the height of Parisian influence on the world stage. Late in the 19th century, Paris hosted two major international expositions: the 1889 Universal Exposition, was held to mark the centennial of the French Revolution and featured the new Eiffel Tower.

"and all"; and everything else:

"and all that" informal; and everything related to the subject mentioned: [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and?q=and%20all%20that)

Comment: I have never heard that expression before, and NGrams hasn't either... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+that%27s+french&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url= Your explanation of "for a liver pill" doesn't seem to fit either: where does "will be fine" come from?

Comment: @JavaLatte "will be fine" come from? - Get your Stomach straight and the rest follows = get your stomach in good order and the rest will follow. Straight; (adjective)  in the sense of in order. Definition: in good order
"and all that" informal; and everything related to the subject mentioned: